# 90 in 180 days Schengen rule verification

Tags: schengen, international-travel, 90-180-visa-rules

I am a non-Schengen country citizen, but I possess a Spanish (TIE) resident card, valid until May 2, 2020 (issued in August 2018).

From December 2, 2019 to February 14, 2020 I will be staying in Hamburg as part of a research visit.
I spent 23 days in France this summer (from July 26 to August 17). 
So in principle, I need to be careful not to violate the 90-180 day Schengen rule.

The company inviting me to Germany will be closed from December 24 to January 5. I can thus return to Spain during this period, so mathematically everything should add up.

My questions are the following.

> How can I prove that I spent the period from December 24 to January 5 in Spain, given that passports are not scanned at airport check-ins for flights between Schengen countries? 
>   Can I have issues with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retain proof of your flight to and from Spain

- boarding card and ticket

which would show that you returned to Spain and again came back.

---

> Do you have any reference indicating whether this is enough?

The [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) should also cover this scenario

- which mainly refers to those who lack an entry/exit stamp

In this scenario, your are returning/leaving an area where you have a **resident permit** and where the 90/180 rule (short stay) **does not** apply.

> Article 12
>   **Presumption as regards fulfilment of conditions of duration of stay**
>   ...
>   2. The presumption referred to in paragraph 1 may be rebutted where the third-country national **provides, by any means, credible evidence, such as transport tickets or proof of his or her presence outside the territory of the Member States**, that he or she has respected the conditions relating to the duration of a short stay.

In this context **outside the territory of the Member States** means

- where you have a **resident permit** and the 90/180 rule (short stay) **does not** apply.

---

**Sources**:

- [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407)

  - 2017-03-18 M2